# How to merge this preg replaces? php

Tags: php, preg-replace

Does someone know how to make one preg replace from this two?
It should cut off: https://, http://, https://www., http://www. or only www.

```
preg_replace("/^www\./", "", preg_replace("/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/", "", $hostname, 1), 1);
```

Comment: Try `"/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/"`

Comment: "/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www.)?/" it works I found it